# How to implement search functionality with Laravel lighthouse-php and vuejs?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Backend Laravel with scout and algolia search, Lighthouse-php

Below laravel grapql:

`products(search: String @search, orderBy: _ @orderBy(columns: ["created_at"])): [Product!]! @paginate`

Graphql-playground search work perfectly:

```
  products(first: 5, search: $searchText) {
    data {
      id
      name
      description
    }
     paginatorInfo {
      currentPage
      lastPage
    }

  }
}
```

Vue template need advice how to complete my code with search functionality?:

```
<template>
  <div class="py-16 px-16 text-gray-800">
    <div>
      Search
      <input v-model="search" type="search" />
    </div>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.slug">
      ?????
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ALL_PRODUCTS from '@/graphql/AllProducts.gql'

export default {
  apollo: {
    products: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      query: ALL_PRODUCTS,
      variables() {
        return {
          searchText: this.search,
        }
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.search
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: 'Products',
  },
}
</script>
```

Please advice. Thank you!

Comment: doesn't look like proper, complete query, where is variable definition? really tested in graphiql **using query variables**?

Comment: tested with graphql playground

Comment: hardcoded or using query variables? exact query and variables used in test?

Comment: exact query and variables!

Comment: show this 'exact query and variables'

Comment: {
  "searchText": "pizza"
}

Comment: and query? looks like first line missing .... https://www.howtographql.com/vue-apollo/3-mutations-creating-links/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolve my issue:

```
  <div class="py-16 px-16 text-gray-800">
    <div>
      Search
      <input v-model="search" type="search" @input="searchResults()" />
    </div>
    <div v-if="products">
      <div v-for="product in products.data" :key="product.slug">
        <NuxtLink
          :to="{ name: 'products-slug', params: { slug: product.slug } }"
          >{{ product.name }}</NuxtLink
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ALL_PRODUCTS from '@/graphql/AllProducts.gql'

export default {
  apollo: {
    products: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      query: ALL_PRODUCTS,
      variables() {
        return {
          searchText: this.search,
        }
      },
      skip() {
        return !this.search
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    searchResults() {
      return this.products
    },
  },
  head: {
    title: 'Products',
  },
}
</script>
```